# Take Social Security at 65 or spend retirement savings

Tags: united-states, retirement, ira, social-security

What is better?  To retire at 65 1/2 and spend nothing but retirement savings until reaching age 70. At 70 take social security for both me and my wife and get the maximum benefit.  I would spend $430k of my 401k savings but receive an additional $900 per month in social security for life.

Comment: What is your best guess for the life expectancy of both you and your wife? I know it sounds macabre, but that is going to be a major determinant for which option is better.

Comment: BTW: I would not trust such an important decision to an answer from the Internet. Find a retirement planner that understands SS backwards and forwards. This decision is FAR more complex than you are thinking. For example the age you can claim benefits is not the same for everyone, the amount you get changes monthly depending on when you claim, and whether you or your spouse claim first (or at the same time) makes a big impact.

Comment: Social Security benefits increase at (IIRC) 8% a year.  Can you find an investment that's guaranteed to do better?

Comment: @jamesqf Your assessment of the situation is not how one should think about it. Even if one has an investment that earns 0% each year, that investment has the same value at age 70 as it did at age 65 (ignoring inflation). On the other hand, if the SS benefit is not claimed at age 65 but delayed till age 70, yes, the amount of the benefit will increase at 8% per year and the OP will get a larger benefit **starting** at age 70, but at age 70 his "investment" will have value 0 because he never received the money in the first place!

Comment: @Dilip Sarwate: I suggest that it's your assessment that's wrong.  It's exactly the same as e.g. buying an annuity (the "investment"): if you pay $X, the monthly amount you receive will be larger if you start taking it at 70 vs 65.  Assuming you have adequate funds to live in the intervening period, you're better off waiting if the interest rate is better than you can get elsewhere.  (Of course this is more complicated if you're married, or want to leave money to your heirs if you die early.)

Comment: @jamesqf I wish you joy in your retirement.

Comment: @jamesqf Eventually yes the delayed start will result in you getting more money. But it will not be until some years after age 70. As Dilip Sarwate explained by taking money sooner you have years of income at the lower rate as opposed to years of $0.  At some point two lines cross and delaying becomes better. Though if you are able to invest the SS then the cross over point is even further down the road.

Comment: @Eric Johnson: But if you don't have immediate need for that income, why take it rather than letting it grow?  Of course, if you can find somewhere to invest it that will return better than an inflation-protected 8% per year (with the same sort of guarantee), then you should take the money and invest there.  But I don't know of any such investment, alas.

Comment: @jamesqf If you expect to live long enough, then yes let it grow. But if your personal medical history suggests that you will not be alive at the crossover point then you are better taking the money sooner.

Comment: @Eric Johnson: Assuming you don't have any immediate use for the money before your probable death, how do YOU benefit?  Do you get points for dying with extra cash?  (Of course some people may want to leave more for their heirs, but that's a different issue.)  And if medical science comes up with a miracle cure and you don't die after all, you win :-)

Comment: Life expectancy has decreased in the past two years and is expected to continue to do so because people are delaying screenings and care out of fear of being exposed to Covid.

Answer (score 6):

As JohnFx suggests in a comment, one's *personal* life expectancy is something to take into account in deciding whether to start taking Social
Security benefits early or to defer them till age 70 "because the 
monthly benefit increases till age 70 but not beyond that."
*Roughly speaking,* if you live exactly as long as the official estimate
of life expectancy, then the total sum of the monthly benefits that 
you will receive over your lifetime
is the same regardless of whether you start earlier or at age 70. That is,
the so-called increase in the Social Security monthly benefit 
if you delay taking benefits beyond your normal retirement age is
*at least in part* due to the fact that a
"fixed pot of money" is being divided into larger chunks at age 70
(fewer months to live) than at age 67 (more months to live).

Thus, as a simple rule of thumb,
if you are in poor health or heredity is against you and
so you don't anticipate living a long time after retirement, start
your Social Security benefits early. If you are in excellent health
and everyone in your family lived past 90 years of age, start taking
benefits at age 70.

Note that this is just one part of the big picture. Spousal benefits
and spousal life expectancy is also part of the decision, etc.

---

Contrary to what jamesqf seems to be arguing vigorously for in the comments on the main question as well as on Kate Gregory's answer,
if one chooses to **delay** starting Social Security benefits at age 65,
then the monthly benefit increases at approximately 8% per year until
age 70, but when the benefits *start* at age 70, **the recipient does not
get a lump sum consisting of the sum of all the monthly benefits that were foregone from 65 to 70**.  So, the notion of *"do you have an
investment in mind that will increase at 8% per year"* is not relevant.

- If you take the benefit at age 65 and *invest* it (instead of spending
  it for living expenses), you have (hopefully) all that money plus
  some gains in that
  investment at age 70. Your benefits continue at that same lower level
  past age 70 too.
- If you don't take the benefit at age 65 and wait
  till 70, there is **no investment** (your living expenses are covered
  elsewhere as in the previous scenario), and you have 0 investment
  at age 70.
  Starting at age 70, you get a monthly benefit that is higher than
  in the previous scenario, and you can start investing it from
  then onward.

Under both scenarios, if you live until *exactly* your life expectancy
(perhaps committing suicide on that day so as to not prove the government
wrong), the *total* sum of money that you receive under both scenarios
is the same. If you are fortunate enough to have not needed to use
any of the SS benefit for living expenses and invested it all, then we can discuss what rates of growth can be expected from the investment, and
whether you die richer in one scenario versus the other. But the sad
truth is that for most Americans, the Social Security benefit is a
major source (if not the only source) of their living expenses in
retirement, and very little of the money is likely to be invested.

Comment: "If you take the benefit at age 65 and invest it..." Yes, but where will you find an investment that is (pretty well - barring revolution &c) guaranteed to return 8%.  Yes, if you save & invest everything between 65 and 70, you will have the lump sum plus investment returns, but if at age 70 you invest that total, you will probably see less income going forward than you would get from the increased SS payment.

Comment: @jamesqf Once again, I wish you all the best in your retirement, and pray to God that you will have enough other income that you can invest your Social Security monthly payment in exactly the manner that will yield the maximum benefit to you as determined by _your_ understanding of the facts.

Comment: Instead of wishing, why not just do the math, which will quickly demonstrate that you're wrong?

Comment: @jamesqf I just did the math, based on my current SSA Retirement Benefits Calculator and -- based on a life expectancy of 80 years -- I'd get within a percent difference of **total SS benefits** by retiring at ages 65, 66 and 67.

Comment: @RonJohn: I don't disagree, but the life expectancy of 80 years seems awfully pessimistic for someone who is in good health at 65.  Which is why the optimum strategy depends on one's health.  IOW, the SSA has tried to set the benefit increase so that if one lives exactly to one's actuarial life expectancy, the numbers should come out the same.

Comment: @jamesqf your flaw is in expecting that everyone is healthy at age 65.  (The average life expectancy for a middle aged male in the US in 2015 was... **80 years**.)  https://www.ssa.gov/oact/STATS/table4c6.html)

Comment: @RonJohn: No, I am saying just what is stated in this answer.  IF you are in good health at 65 and have no reason to expect that to change, then (all else being equal) you will be better off not taking benefits until you're 70.

Comment: Yes, @jamesqf **IF** you are healthy.  But since the average life expectancy for a middle aged male in the US in 2015 was 80 years, there are going to be a heck of a lot of **DEAD** men who would have been 80 **if they hadn't died**.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer. Can this entire comment thread be moved to a chat room? I tried to set up a chat room but couldn't figure out how to move this thread into it.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Using your numbers, the answer is clearly NO. Ignore interest, inflation, and the time value of money. If I asked you to give up $430,000 now for $900 a month (11,000 a year) for the rest of your life, how long would it take to "earn back" the $430,000? Well, after FORTY YEARS of $11,000 a year, you would have $440,000. Are you likely to live past age 110? No. Using the numbers you've provided, you're ahead taking it at 65.

However, I don't think your numbers are right. If you're going to use up $430,000 in less than 5 years, you're going through over $7000 a month, and taking Social Security now will not pay you that. So presumably you're going to use up some of that $430,000 no matter what and you should be looking at the difference and seeing how long the payback period is. Will you break even at age 80, 90, 100? Perhaps it's worth taking the time to do the calculation with interest, inflation, taxes, and so on. Typically the people who decide how much extra you get for delaying are taking expected lifespans into account, so I would expect you to get a number that makes the decision quite difficult.

Another relevant question is this: If you plan to spend $7,000 a month of after-tax money, how big a difference is $900 a month anyway? Seems like bringing your spend down by 13% would be a better goal.

Comment: Can you try rephrasing this answer? I've re-read it about three times and don't follow what you are saying. Where are you getting the 40 years from?

Comment: 11,000 * 40 = 440,000

Comment: I'm still not following this answer at all.

Comment: Someone wants to use up 440k in order to gain 11k a year after that. I am pointing out it will take 40 years to pull back even. I don't think the op will live to age 110

Comment: Kate, respectfully, the math doesn't work. He will blow through $440K in 4.5 years, 54 months? That's $8148/mo. Say he takes SS now. He will still be drawing down his saving, even if only $5500/month or so. OP needs to spell out the current benefit vs future benefit for this to make any sense.

Comment: @Kate Gregory: What you're overlooking is that the maximum SS benefit for someone retiring at 65 is currently  $2639 (per Google).  4.5 years of that is only $142.5K, not $430K.

Comment: @jamesqf the 430 came from the OP, not my guess at the benefits that are being given up.

Comment: @Kate Gregory: Then either the OP's stating his entire retirement spending, not the SS benefit he would forego, or he's really bad at math :-)

Comment: +1 for trying to address this. "trying", because OP really didn't give the full details needed. And last visit was the day after he posted the question.